# CSS formatting different firefox/chrome after resets

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, shopify

With a heavy heart I bring another reset question to the hivemind.  In all browsers besides Firefox, my page has an element set perfectly.  In Firefox, the spacing is off such that it now overlaps another element.

#### I have tried:

1. 6+ different online CSS resets
2. normalize.css
3. Yahoo's javascript reset script
4. the universal reset *

How can it be that these elements are being rendered so differently?

page: http://teknik-hand-holds-2.myshopify.com/collections/all/products/arnold

password: testpage  (the site is still in development)

Comment: Which element are you referring to.  The closest thing I can find is the password box getting closer to the button but it's not overlapping

Comment: Is your question is about the slideshow thumbs? you should explain more clearly!

Comment: what i understand from your problem you have issues with style reset sheet???

Comment: Comparing Mozilla and Chromium, I see the "search" button is somewhat higher up on the screen in Chromium. Nothing overlapping though.